# Atribute FileProvider is presented at two libraries

Tags: android, flutter, android-fileprovider

After adding new library (.aar) file to android I am getting an error:

```
Attribute provider#androidx.core.content.FileProvider@authorities value=(gov.pulsocare.mobile.test.provider) from [aiocare_sdk_2.aar] AndroidManifest.xml:48:13-60
is also present at [higosdk-0.0.11.aar] AndroidManifest.xml:30:13-64 value=(gov.pulsocare.mobile.test.fileprovider).
Suggestion: add 'tools:replace="android:authorities"' to <provider> element at AndroidManifest.xml:46:9-54:20 to override.
```

And second error:

```
Attribute meta-data#android.support.FILE_PROVIDER_PATHS@resource value=(@xml/provider_paths) from [aiocare_sdk_2.aar] AndroidManifest.xml:53:17-55
is also present at [higosdk-0.0.11.aar] AndroidManifest.xml:35:17-50 value=(@xml/filepaths).
Suggestion: add 'tools:replace="android:resource"' to <meta-data> element at AndroidManifest.xml to override.
```

I tried adding tools:replace="android:resource" as described but im not really android dev and I dont really know what to do ( adding this tag dosen't help and I'm not really sure where to add it since I dont have any meta-data tag)

Any comments describing what to try/do will be appreciated

Comment: Somehow, you appear to have two libraries trying to add a `ContentProvider` with the same authority (`gov.pulsocare.mobile.test.provider`). Authorities have to be unique. You might try to track down both whoever `gov.pulsocare` is, along with the developers of `aiocare_sdk_2.aar` and `higosdk-0.0.11.aar`, to try to determine if these libraries are able to be used at the same time in the same app.

Comment: They have to be uses at the same time in the same app but for this example let's say I wanna use ContentProvider from aiocare_sdk_2.aar, Can i somehow. override it?

Comment: I do not know how the other library will work, and I do not know exactly how to tell the manifest merger process which library's provider you want to use.

Answer (score 0):

Delete this from your `AndroidManifest.xml` since `higosdk-0.0.11.aar` already has it.

```
    <provider
        android:name="androidx.core.content.FileProvider"
        android:authorities="${applicationId}.fileprovider"
        android:exported="false"
        android:grantUriPermissions="true">
            <meta-data
                android:name="android.support.FILE_PROVIDER_PATHS"
                android:resource="@xml/provider_paths" />
    </provider>
```

I was just facing this types of issues and the above approach solved them.